# Pandas datetime object comparison

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intersection

I have 2 dataframes. One contains a date range by listing a start date-time, end date-time, and duration. This is a list of times when it was snowing. I next have a dataframe that contains a list of events in a date-time format. This is a list of vehicle crashes. I am trying to find which vehicle crashes fall into which storm event (if any). Is there a simple pandas function that would do this? It seems like a common enough of a situation. I have tried to doctor something together on my own by I keep hitting road blocks. It seems like I can compare dates with (>, <, etc) within a dataframe but comparing between the 2 seems to cause issues.

```
    print(data['SnowStartTimes'] < data['StormEndsTimes'])
```

gives me:

```
    0     True
    1     True ………..
```

however

```
    print(crash['Date+Time'] > data['SnowStartTimes'] & crash['Date+Time'] < data['StormEndsTimes'])
```

gives me 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
'. I think if I could solve the 'ValueError' I could make something work. I am not a well seasoned coder so perhaps there are some fundamentals I am missing.